# Only last tee writes to file (possible overlap with exec?)

Tags: bash, redirection, exec, tee

I try to have all my outputs redirected to `a.out`, except some that must **also** be written to `b.out`. I think using exec on top of tee (tee to also redirect to b.out) would be fine but tee does not look like always have the same behaviour (only the last one seems to work):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > a.out
ls /boot |tee  b.out  #redirected to a.out only!
ls /var  |tee  b.out  #redirected to a.out only!
ls /run  |tee  b.out  #redirected to a.out only!
ls /home |tee  b.out  #redirected to a.out and b.out (good)
echo "a"              #redirected to a.out (good)
```

Same thing for ksh. For info, none of the ls cause an error. Why des tee sometimes fails to fork the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `tee` opens `b.out` on its own and overwrites it on its own. At the very end you see `b.out` from the last `tee` only (note this is independent from the previous `exec`, so the original question title "`tee` inside `exec`, random redirect behaviour" was rather misleading).

If you examined `b.out` between `tee`-s, you would notice it contains the output of the preceding `tee` only. You can do this by typing your commands one by one (without redirecting to `a.out`) and invoking `cat b.out` after each.

Redirection to `a.out` is somewhat different. When you `exec`, `a.out` is opened by the shell just once and everything that is redirected to it gets appended.

Solution: use `tee -a`. From [`man tee`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee):

> `-a`, `--append`
>   append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite

Comment: I feel bad for not even applying the simplest rule of code debugging - one line at a time. also, it was prety obvious that tee did not append but overwrote by default. Thanks, I will edit the question title as suggested.